# Vote counts on "Voters" tab doesn't match counts in Users profile pages

Tags: bug, status-norepro, users, votes

Basically it's this issue again:

[Why is the total vote count different in user's profile and on voters tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123536/why-is-the-total-vote-count-different-in-users-profile-and-on-voters-tab)

But only on Mi Yodeya; I checked several other sites, and none of them had this problem.

---

Edit: This is no longer happening.

Comment: No screenshots now. I may grab them later, if necessary.